# Microsoft Graph Api -No permission acces token when asking for Me.Photo

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I made sure I have all permissions to get user profile photo when using Microsoft graph api, but I get 'no permission Token' error, every time. It doesn't make sens as I can retrive all the other info like DirectReports an Manager - using the same Token.

I have tried Different endpoints and different call like Me.Photo.Content and Users[id].Photo - but still no luck

```
ProfilePhoto GetAvatarForCurrentUser(GraphServiceClient  _graphServiceClient)
    {

        using (var task = Task.Run(async () => await _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Request().GetAsync()))
        {
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var avatar = task.Result;
            return avatar;
        }     
    }



public ProfilePhoto GetAvatar()
    {
        var accessToken = GetAppTokenForAvatar();
        var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
     {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));

        var userAvatar = GetAvatarForCurrentUser(graphserviceClient);

        return userAvatar as Microsoft.Graph.ProfilePhoto;
     }



public string GetAppTokenForAvatar()
     {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[app-id]/");

        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(Config.AdClientID, Config.AdClientKey);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCred).Result;
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
     }
```

I Expect to recive my own profile avatar, and like I said I have no problem to get Menager or other related data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AuthenticationContext is not correct. When you use the wrong AuthenticationContext, you will encounter such error.

[image]

Replace

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[app-id]/");
```

with

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/");
```

Based on your code, you are using client credentials, you should use `Users[id].Photo`. And make sure you grant admin consent for application permission.

[image]

Comment: This have sorted my issue, Thanks!